# Issue using the Oracle Command Parameters

Tags: c#, oracle, asp.net-web-api, system.data.oracleclient

Trying to create a Web API which queries the Oracle DB which receives the input as array of String.So trying to add Command Parameters

I added the following references System.Data.OracleClient.dll also,

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter;
using System.Data.OracleClient;
using System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter;
```

But getting error as below
[image]

`A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter' is a type not a namespace

A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter' is a type not a namespace `

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use both Oracle's Oracle client (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client) and Microsoft's Oracle client (System.Data.OracleClient). You should pick one of them. However, I think the Microsoft one is deprecated in more recent .Net Framework releases so you're probably better off with Oracle's implementation.

Comment: Which one should I be adding here

Comment: If I just add `using System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter` getting  Error 1 A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter' is a type not a namespace

Comment: Exactly.  System.Data.OracleClient has been depricated for a LONG time.  And it's beyond terrible.  If you are using a Web app, I'd use standard ODP.net rather than the managed client.  The managed client is fine, but it's missing functionality in the original version such as bulk inserts.

Comment: And parameters on System.Data.OracleClient are beyond terrible.  Seriously, switch now!

Comment: I myself would use the `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` because the Microsoft isn't available in the more recent versions of the .Net framework.

Comment: Are you asking me to just use just `using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter` I removed the reference to  System.Data.OracleClient also removed using System.Data.OracleClient but still I am getting Error 1 A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter' is a type not a namespace

Comment: there is a statement inside my code as `OracleParameter p = new OracleParameter(":p" + x, OracleType.Int32)` which throws error like OracleType is not in correct context if I remove the System.Data.OracleClient reference

Comment: I am kind of really stuck please help me with this

Comment: You need to remove `using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter` because that is the fully qualified type name for `OracleParameter` and `using` statements can only have namespaces.

Comment: I did remove them.I currently have just `using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System.Data.OracleClient;` Still seeing errors on the where ever I am referencing the OracleParameter as Error 1 'OracleParameter' is an ambiguous reference between 'Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleParameter' and 'System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter'

Comment: Double-check the references in your project and in other that are in your solution. Make sure none reference System.Data.OracleClient.

Have you specified any of your types as `System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter` in your code? If you have you should change it to only OracleParameter. If you have other source files, do any of them have `using System.Data.OracleClient.OracleParameter` in them? You should remove those also.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120065/discussion-between-trx-and-richard).